# Bracket in the shape of a horse bow

Tags: symbols, brackets

I'm wondering how to make a bracket that looks a bit like "(" and ")" but with the middle part curving inwards a bit. The result should look like a horse bow. This is not to be confused with "{", which has a pointy middle instead of a round one, and doesn't curve inwards. I imagine I will need to make a new TeX macro, but I don't know TeX.

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: There are several strange delimiter pairs already, and there is a chance that what you look for is already there. Not that it helps, but may I ask how this bow should be used?

Comment: @mickep It's a new notation for pairs of matrices $[A,B]$. I use square brackets at the moment, but those can be confused with Lie brackets. I've tried looking up macros for a horse (or "recurve") bow here: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: I use the notation $[A,B]$ at the moment because the matrix-pair is actually a matrix over the algebra $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$, defined to equal $(1,0)A + (0,1)B^T$. I use square brackets instead of round brackets because I think it indicates that the transpose gets used, somehow.

Comment: It might be best to use an existing bracket symbol. What about ⦗⦘ or ⦃⦄?

Comment: Or ⟦⟧  or ⁅ ⁆ or ⟬⟭ or ⦋⦌ ? I am sure there are others, too. I am not a mathematician by any means, so some might be reserved for other purposes, but surely using existing Unicode characters is preferable to coming up with your own (necessarily obscure) brackets.